# Realm Transaction without notifying tokens

Tags: swift, realm

I have Realm notifications on a background thread created with the following code (taken from Realm's website)

```swift
class BackgroundWorker: NSObject {

    private let name: String
    private var thread: Thread!
    private var block: (()->Void)!


    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    @objc internal func runBlock() {
        block()
    }

    internal func start(_ block: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.block = block
        if thread == nil {
            createThread()
        }

        perform(
            #selector(runBlock),
            on: thread,
            with: nil,
            waitUntilDone: false,
            modes: [RunLoop.Mode.default.rawValue]
        )
    }


    private func createThread() {
        thread = Thread { [weak self] in
            while (self != nil && !self!.thread.isCancelled) {
                RunLoop.current.run(
                    mode: RunLoop.Mode.default,
                    before: Date.distantFuture)
            }
            Thread.exit()
        }
        thread.name = name
        thread.start()
    }

    func stop() {
        thread.cancel()
    }

}
```

And using the background worker like this

```
struct RealmBackGroundWorker {

  static var tokens: [NotificationToken] = []
  static let backgroundWorker = BackGroundWorker(name: "RealmWorker")

  static func start() {
    backgroundWorker.start {
      self.tokens = ...
    }
  }
}
```

The background notifications work great. But I often need to save data to realm without notifying these transactions. From what I have found, it does not look like there is a way write data without notifying all tokens. You always have to specify the tokens you want to ignore.
How can I write data to the Realm without notifying these background tokens?

Comment: May I ask why you're doing this? e.g. what's the use case Also, are you wrapping your background calls in an autorelease pool? Lastly, you can selectively suppress notifications by passing a specific token (or an array of tokens) to `.write(withoutNotifying`. When you say 'all tokens' what does that mean?

Comment: I am using these background tokens to sync data to a server. Sometimes, I do not want to sync local changes to the server, so I would like to call `.write(withouNotifying: RealmWorkBlock.tokens)`. But this crashes, telling me that I can only ignore tokens on the realm they were created on (this is a summary of the crash dialog).

Comment: Are you using a Full Sync or Partial Sync? Also this `.write(withoutNotifying` doesn't have anything to do with sync'ing - it has to do with notifications. The idea with that function is that if you update your UI manually, you don't want to receive an additional notification event that could overwrite what you did. So it won't prevent or alter syncing, just the notifications that go with it. That error is correct as the token is tied to the notification of the thread it was registered on. It's possible your code could be greatly simplified which is why I was asking how it being used.

Comment: I am not using full or partial sync.  I have notifications running on a background thread.  I want a way to write data to the realm database without notifying these notifications.

Comment: Question: The backgroundworker contains one thread (one run loop) and therefore one token. Why is the tokens var defined as an array `static var tokens: [NotificationToken] = []`? This code `self.tokens = ...` makes it look like several tokens would be returned from one runloop. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this answer with a couple of things. The Realm website the OP got their code from was here [Realm Notifications on Background Threads with Swift](https://academy.realm.io/posts/realm-notifications-on-background-threads-with-swift/) and part of the point of that code was to not only spin up a runloop on a background thread to handle Realm functions but to also handle notifications on that same thread.

That code is pretty old - 4+ years and is somewhat outdated. In essence, there are possibly better options. From Apple:

> ... newer technologies such as Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) provide a
>   more modern and efficient infrastructure for implementing concurrency

But to address the question, if an observer is added to a Realm results on thread A, then all of the notifications will also occur on thread A. e.g. the token returned from the observe function is tied to that thread.

It appears the OP wants to write data without receiving notifications

> I do not want to sync local changes to the server, so I would like to
>   call .write(withouNotifying: RealmWorkBlock.tokens)

and

> I want a way to write data to the realm database without notifying
>   these notifications.

Noting that those notifications will occur on the same thread as the runloop. Here's the code that we need to look at

```
  static func start() {
    backgroundWorker.start {
      self.tokens = ...
    }
```

and in particular this line

```
self.tokens = ...
```

because the ... is the important part. That ... leads to this line (from the docs)

```
self?.token = files.observe { changes in
```

which is where the observer is added that generates the notifications. If no notifications are needed then that code, starting with self?.token can be completely removed as that's is sole purpose - to generate notifications.

One thought is to add a different init to the background worker class to have a background worker with no notifications:

```
static func start() {
   backgroundWorker.startWithoutNotifications()
}
```

Another thought is to take a more modern approach and leverage DispatchQueue with an autorelease pool which eliminates the need for these classes completely, will run in the background freeing up the UI ad does not involve tokens or notifications.

```
DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
    autoreleasepool {
      let realm = try! Realm()
      let files = realm.objects(File.self).filter("localUrl = ''")
    }
}
```